# Problem executing query for SQL Server in C# with SQLDataReader

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute a query in C# using `SqlDataReader` but I receive an error message from the database, "**Incorrect syntax near '.'**".

I am not sure what is wrong with my SQL query. I can execute it perfectly fine in SQL Server Management Studio.

```
try
{
   SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection();
   thisConnection.Open();
   SqlCommand thisCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
   thisCommand.CommandText = "SELECT"
                +"db.name DBName,"
                +"tl.request_session_id,"
                +"wt.blocking_session_id,"
                +"OBJECT_NAME(p.OBJECT_ID) BlockedObjectName,"
                +"tl.resource_type,"
                +"h1.TEXT AS RequestingText,"
                +"h2.TEXT AS BlockingText,"
                +"tl.request_mode"
                +"FROM sys.dm_tran_locks AS tl"
                +"INNER JOIN sys.databases db ON db.database_id = tl.resource_database_id"
                +"INNER JOIN sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks AS wt ON tl.lock_owner_address = wt.resource_address"
                +"INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p ON p.hobt_id = tl.resource_associated_entity_id"
                +"INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections ec1 ON ec1.session_id = tl.request_session_id"
                +"INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections ec2 ON ec2.session_id = wt.blocking_session_id"
                +"CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec1.most_recent_sql_handle) AS h1"
                +"CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec2.most_recent_sql_handle) AS h2";

   SqlDataReader thisReader = thisCommand.ExecuteReader();
   while (thisReader.Read())
   {
      Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", thisReader["DBName"], thisReader["BlockedObjectName"]);
   }
   thisReader.Close();
   thisConnection.Close();
}
catch (SqlException e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: Recommendations: put your IDisposable `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` into `using(....) { ... }` blocks to ensure proper disposal; open your connection AS LATE as possible - just before `ExecuteReader` - and not any earlier.

Comment: I fixed the syntax error with my SQL query. Now I get an "Enumeration yields no result" error after thisReader.Read() is executed. Im not sure why that is

Answer (score 16):

You need spaces at the end of some of the lines you are concatenating:

For example:

```
            +"tl.request_mode"
            +"FROM sys.dm_tran_locks AS tl"
```

Will create the SQL

```
 ...tl.request_modeFROM sys.dm_tran_locks AS tl...
```

Change it to

```
            +"tl.request_mode " 
            +"FROM sys.dm_tran_locks AS tl"
```

There are also a few other lines with the same problem.

This is a good example of why it is important to actually print out the concatenated string when testing a dynamically built SQL string instead of just pasting the code and editing out the quotes and + signs.

Comment: and if you're going to use a concatenated string, use StringBuilder

Comment: @Brian - In this case it probably won't make a difference. If all the strings are literals like this, the compiler will combine them in a single string in the MSIL anyway. However, I'd still think just putting a @ on the front of the string and losing all the +"" business would be more readable anyway.

Comment: I was about to say the same thing, the only drawback of the @ method is if tabs are left in the CIL looks like `"SELECT\r\n\t\t\t\t\tdb.Name DBName,\r\n\t\t\t\t\t"` etc. Makes for a pain when using Reflector to look at production code (when you aren't sure what version is deployed...)

Answer (score 2):

As John mentioned you need spaces at the end of your lines as you are missing a few.

As an example your initial error is coming from the first two lines

```
thisCommand.CommandText = "SELECT" 
                +"db.name DBName,"
```

which will equal

```
SELECTdb.name DBName,
```

Thats where the "**Incorrect syntax near**'.'" is coming from as **db.** is being added onto the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1):

JohnFx and kevchadders are right that the error is due to the resulting string not having appropriate whitespace.  As for what you can do about it - if you'd like the query to remain more or less in the same format, you can use @-quoting:

```
thisCommand.CommandText = 
@"SELECT
    db.name DBName,
    tl.request_session_id,
    wt.blocking_session_id,
    OBJECT_NAME(p.OBJECT_ID) BlockedObjectName,
    tl.resource_type,
    h1.TEXT AS RequestingText,
    h2.TEXT AS BlockingText,
    tl.request_mode
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks AS tl
INNER JOIN sys.databases db ON db.database_id = tl.resource_database_id
INNER JOIN sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks AS wt ON tl.lock_owner_address = wt.resource_address
INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p ON p.hobt_id = tl.resource_associated_entity_id
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections ec1 ON ec1.session_id = tl.request_session_id
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections ec2 ON ec2.session_id = wt.blocking_session_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec1.most_recent_sql_handle) AS h1
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec2.most_recent_sql_handle) AS h2
";

SqlDataReader thisReader = thisCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

This will respect your line ends and other whitespace so you get to have a readable query you can easily copy-paste from the C# into SSMS, without the whitespace errors, without concatenation, and without all the StringBuilder.Append statements.